# The systemd service didn't start on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, systemd

4 systemd service is created to start 4 besu processes on ubuntu 20.04 server under `/etc/systemd/system/besu`. Here is the `node1.service`:

```
cjadmin@ibm-testbox:/etc/systemd/system/besu$ cat node1.service

[Unit]
Description=Besu Enterprise Ethereum java client
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=myuser
Environment=HOME=/home/myuser
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/home/myuser/bin/besu/bin/besu --config-file=/home/myuser/bin/besu_network/node1/config.toml >> /var/log/besu/node1.log 2>&1"  #<<==start besu service with configuration in  config.toml
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The others are `node2.service` to `node4.service`. After reboot the server, there is no log files under `/var/log/besu/`. Then I check the system log by `dmesg | less` and didn't find any error and didn't see logs for starting besu services as wll. What can be wrong for the systemd services failing to start? Where to see the error?

Update:

```
$ systemctl status /etc/systemd/system/besu/node1.service
Unit etc-systemd-system-besu-node1.service.mount could not be found.
$ systemctl status node1.service
Unit node1.service could not be found.
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo systemctl enable node1.service` (same steps for the other ones) and then `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: No. Just created the service files and reboot.I thought the reboot shall load the service at bootup.

Comment: same problem after sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/besu/node1.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/node1.service → /etc/systemd/system/besu/node1.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/node1.service → /etc/systemd/system/besu/node1.service.

Comment: after moving service files to /etc/systemd/system/ and it was picked up by the system.